# Difference between class_weight and loss_weights arguments in TensorFlow/Keras

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, keras, tensorflow, class-imbalance

I am creating a neural network using TensorFlow (v2.9.2) for an imbalanced image dataset. While doing so, I noticed that `model.compile()` method has an argument `loss_weights`, and `model.fit()` has an argument `class_weight`. I know that the `loss_weights` argument would transform the loss function to a weighted one and propagate the loss proportionately. But I am confused about the `class_weight` argument.

My questions:

**1. In what way do they differ from each other, specifically in terms of affecting the training process?**

**2. Should the value of `class_weight` argument be the same as `loss_weights` argument, considering that the distribution ratios among the categories remain the same throughout the process?**

Answer (score 0):

`loss_weight` is more related to having two loss functions when having two outputs from your model, but `class_weight` is more related to your data since you have imbalanced dataset.

Please check `model.compile()` [documentation](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/v2.11.0/keras/engine/training.py#L596-L762).

So it is not necessary that the values of these arguments be the same.